# listview row is not getting focus in android

Tags: android, android-listview

Below is the code for the adapter for a `listview`

### What is happening:

- here there is a image view `onclick` i change the background of it
- but say i clicked the first row `imageview`, it changes the background
  & immateriality when i click the following row `imageview` it wont
  change the background but when i click for the second time(2nd row)
  `imageview` changes the background
- So I am having problems with focus-ability, how can i resolve this

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" 
>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMsgNameId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLocationId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Location:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtCategoryId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Category:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtAvailId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Availability:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/rtngId"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:numStars="5" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnFavId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/heart_blue" 
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnPhoneId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/phone_red"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/serviceProviderId"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think If you want your list item click able than all you need : make your listview not focusable
try this xml declaration for your list view

```
   <ListView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
      android:focusable="false" />
```